# How I can read content data from properties file to Properties object?

Tags: kotlin

In my Kotlin project in folder **resources** I has properties file. How I can read content data from this file to Properties object?

I try this:

```
 val fis = FileInputStream("resources/pairs_ids.txt")
    prop.load(fis);
    logger.info("ETH_BTC_id = " + prop.get("ETH_BTC"))
```

But I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\pairs_ids.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Answer (score 12):

what I like to do in this case is something like:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> getProp(key: String): T {
    val props  = javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("pairs_ids.txt").use {
        Properties().apply { load(it) }
    }
    return (props.getProperty(key) as T) ?: throw RuntimeException("could not find property $key")
}
```

it will read the properties and tries to cast a certain property. 
because of kotlins type inference it can then be used like this:

```
val foo: String = getProp("ETH_BTC")
```

or this:

```
val foo = getProp<String>("ETH_BTC")
```

Answer (score 6):

```
val props = Properties()
props.load(...)
props.getProperty("key")
```

That is the same as with Java

Comment: The relative path (without drive name on Windows or slash on Mac/Linux) is resolved from the current working directory of your Java process. You may try the full path instead to make it work. Or check if your working directory.

Should you refer to Java resource files? Than use something like
```
javaClass.classLoader.getResourceStream("pairs_ids.txt")?.use { stream -> props.load(stream) }
```
I omit `resources`, probably you do not need them, but please check what you have in the classpath